# Convert response body blob to json or plain text in javascript

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my cypress test, I have submitted a request and in the response the body returned as `blob`. How can I check the `some text` content in body. Is there any way convert the `blob` into `json or plain text`. Please see the screenshot attached. Adding the test code below

```
cy.request('https://someurlHere).then((response) => {
          expect(response.status).to.eq(200) // this is loooking good
          expect(response).to.have.property('headers')  // this is loooking good
          console.log(response.text());
          //var alertArr = [];
          //alertArr = response.json();
          //console.log(alertArr);
        })
```

[image]

Comment: you can always use `response.json()` or `response.text()` which returns a promise. Once the promise is resolved, you would have the result

Comment: I am getting `response.json()  or response.text()` is not a function ... TypeError: response.text is not a function

Comment: I have added my cypress test code above.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for response.body. See below example.

```js
cy
  .request('POST', 'http://localhost:8888/users/admin', { name: 'Jane' })
  .then((response) => {
    // response.body is automatically serialized into JSON
    expect(response.body).to.have.property('name', 'Jane') // true
  })
```