# Cypress, response body as BLOB instead of JSON, but JSON in chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, blob, cypress

i've been struggling with this behaviour of Cypress that i do not understand and i need help.

When i set route and wait for the request i can see that the response body is in `BLOB`, when in chrome devtools response body arrives as `JSON`, so is in application. I have `Content-type` set to `application/vnd.api+json`. Cypress version 3.7.0. I also disabled `Fetch` because Cypress have problems with that [Cypress documentation #wait](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#When-given-an-alias-argument)

```
 cy.server();
 cy.route('POST', '**/services').as('postService');
 cy.get('[data-cy=AddServices_submit]').click();

 cy.wait('@postService').then((xhr) => {
     //xhr.response.body is BLOB
     //xhr.responseBody is BLOB
 })
```

Found similar question: [Stackoverflow Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666827/convert-response-body-blob-to-json-or-plain-text-in-javascript) but this is not helpful for me.

Did any one had similar problems with response arriving as BLOB?

Any help would be great, if you need more information feel free to ask. Thanks

**EDIT**

I have a workaround to this problem if anyone needed one. But the problem Still occurs

```
cy.wait('@postService').then(async (xhr) => {
    const response = await new Response(xhr.responseBody).text();
    const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
    // jsonResponse is real json
});
```

Comment: Your workaround actually works. I'm in the same situation and that workaround helped... the downvote on this question was not helpful at all.

Comment: This one works as is - `const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(await xhr.responseBody.text());` Is there any reason why you need to wrap it in a new `Response` ?

Comment: @ldiary I wrapped it in Response just because i am using Typescript, and it didn't know what responseBody was even when i Typed xhr. But i think there is no need to do this when there is no typescript

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and it was solved by adding cypress fetch polyfill as [here](https://gist.github.com/yagudaev/2ad1ef4a21a2d1cfe0e7d96afc7170bc)

If the link won't be available, I copy the content here:

In directory `cypress/support/` in file `hooks.js` add this code:

```
// Cypress does not support listening to the fetch method
// Therefore, as a workaround we polyfill `fetch` with traditional XHR which
// are supported. See: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/687
enableFetchWorkaround();

// private helpers
function enableFetchWorkaround() {
  let polyfill;

  before(() => {
    console.info('Load fetch XHR polyfill')
    cy.readFile('./cypress/support/polyfills/unfetch.umd.js').then((content) => {
      polyfill = content
    })
  });

  Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
    delete win.fetch;
    // since the application code does not ship with a polyfill
    // load a polyfilled "fetch" from the test
    win.eval(polyfill);
    win.fetch = win.unfetch;
  })
}
```

In directory `cypress/support/` in file `index.js` import `hooks.js`

```
import './hooks'
```

In directory `cypress/support/` add directory `polyfills` and add there file `unfetch.umd.js` with this code:

```
// cypress/support/polyfills/unfetch.umd.js

// Version: 4.1.0
// from: https://unpkg.com/unfetch/dist/unfetch.umd.js
!function(e,n){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=n():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(n):e.unfetch=n()}(this,function(){return function(e,n){return n=n||{},new Promise(function(t,o){var r=new XMLHttpRequest,s=[],u=[],i={},f=function(){return{ok:2==(r.status/100|0),statusText:r.statusText,status:r.status,url:r.responseURL,text:function(){return Promise.resolve(r.responseText)},json:function(){return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(r.responseText))},blob:function(){return Promise.resolve(new Blob([r.response]))},clone:f,headers:{keys:function(){return s},entries:function(){return u},get:function(e){return i[e.toLowerCase()]},has:function(e){return e.toLowerCase()in i}}}};for(var a in r.open(n.method||"get",e,!0),r.onload=function(){r.getAllResponseHeaders().replace(/^(.*?):[^\S\n]*([\s\S]*?)$/gm,function(e,n,t){s.push(n=n.toLowerCase()),u.push([n,t]),i[n]=i[n]?i[n]+","+t:t}),t(f())},r.onerror=o,r.withCredentials="include"==n.credentials,n.headers)r.setRequestHeader(a,n.headers[a]);r.send(n.body||null)})}});
```

So, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here...

I manage to get the data as JSON when I use `cy.request()` but I can't when I use an alias with `cy.wait()`

Could you try this as a workaround ?

```js
const setBodyAsJson = async (xhr) => ({ ...xhr, body: JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(await xhr.response.body.arrayBuffer()))) })

cy.server();
cy.route('POST', '**/services').as('postService');
cy.get('[data-cy=AddServices_submit]').click();

cy.wait('@postService').then(setBodyAsJson).then((res) => {
    // res should contain body as JSON
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. I have a workaround to this problem (I will edit my question), but i do not understand why it comes as BLOB when everything else says its JSON

Answer (score 0):

This does not explain why but in case your response.body is a `Blob` but `responseBody` is `null`, you can use this to read it:

```
        cy.wait('@postService', TIMEOUT)
        .its('response.body')
        .then(body => {
            return new Promise(done => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function() {
                    done(JSON.parse(this.result));
                };
                reader.readAsText(body);
            });
        })
        .then(object => {
            expect(typeof object).to.equal('object')
        });
```

Comment: I dont need another workaroun. I wrote in edit a workaround i use, which is far more readable than this... i need an explanation why it is not in JSON in the first place

Comment: No need to -1, your workaround does not work for me as `responseBody` is `null` while our response.body is indeed a Blob...

Comment: i gave you -1 because it is not an answer to my question. But giving me -1 just because i gave -1 to you is a bit childlish... dont you think?

Comment: I hate -1’s and never give them... Almost. But the question is a bit nebulous, your posted workaround does not work and you did mention that any help would be appreciated, but it wasn’t, on the contrary. 
I will post again if I find why we receive a blob…